# c# for loop in switch/case situation - how to?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, foreach, switch-statement

I am trying to extend a given code in c# but I am somewhat stuck doe to lack of experience with programming.

Using visual studio community, I am trying to read out CPU core temperatures via console. The code uses a switch/case to find the case for a particular *name* of the sensor, ie **CPU Core #1** and the give the temperature.  For each CPU Core. Having 64 cores, that is quite a copy n paste. I tried to implement a foreach-situation but it doesn't work. Also I don't know how to setup a for loop here.

That's the code in question:

```
if (s.SensorType == LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware.SensorType.Temperature)
{
    if (s.Value != null)
    {
        float curTemp = (float)s.Value;
        switch (s.Name)
        {
            case "Core Average": //average temps
                cpuTemp = curTemp.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                Console.WriteLine(" CPU AVG TEMP: " + cpuTemp);
                Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                break;

            case "CPU Core #": //Temps for CPU Core #1, CPU Core #2 ...
                foreach (s.Name in LibreHardwareMonitor...? ) // <-- no clue what to do here
                {
                    int i = 1;
                    cpuTemp = curTemp.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                    Console.WriteLine(" CPU #" + i +" TEMP: " + cpuTemp);
                    Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                    i++;
                }                    
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am stuck and don't know how to implement to spit out all the **CPU Core#1** to **CPU Core#64** temps.

Here is the complete code:

```
private void dataCheck(object StateObj)
{
    string cpuTempA = ""; 
    string cpuTemp = "";
    string gpuTemp = "";
    string gpuLoad = "";
    string cpuLoad = "";
    string dataUsed = "";
    string fanUsed = "";
    string cpuClock = "";
    //;
    StateObjClass State = (StateObjClass)StateObj;
    // enumerating all the hardware
    foreach (LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware.IHardware hw in thisComputer.Hardware)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HARDWARE: " + hw.HardwareType);
        Console.ReadLine();

        hw.Update();
        // searching for all sensors and adding data to listbox
        foreach (LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware.ISensor s in hw.Sensors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NAME: " + s.Name + ", TYPE: " + s.SensorType + ", VALUE: " + s.Value);
            Console.ReadLine();

            if (s.SensorType == LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware.SensorType.Temperature)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" FOUND " + s.SensorType);
                if (s.Value != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" FOUND VALUE " + s.Value);
                    float curTemp = (float)s.Value;
                    switch (s.Name)
                    {
                        case "Core Average":
                            Console.WriteLine(" FOUND NAME " + s.Name);
                            cpuTempA = curTemp.ToString();

                            Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                            Console.WriteLine(" CPU AVG TEMP: " + cpuTempA);
                            Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                            break;

                        case "CPU Core #": //CPU Core #1, CPU Core #2 ...
                            foreach (s.Name in LibreHardwareMonitor...? )
                            {
                                int i = 1;
                                cpuTemp = curTemp.ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                                Console.WriteLine(" CPU #" + i +" TEMP: " + cpuTemp);
                                Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                                i++;
                            }                    
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }

                if (s.SensorType == LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware.SensorType.Clock)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" FOUND " + s.SensorType);
                    if (s.Value != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(" FOUND VALUE " + s.Value);
                        float curClock = (float)s.Value;
                        switch (s.Name)
                        {
                            case "CPU Core #4":
                                Console.WriteLine(" FOUND NAME " + s.Name);
                                cpuClock = curClock.ToString();
                                Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                                Console.WriteLine(" CPU CLOCK: " + cpuClock);
                                Console.WriteLine(" ... ");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "doesn't work"? Do you get compile errors (please specify), does something happen that you didn't expect (what did you expect and what happened)?

Comment: it doenst run/compile haha - I am a noob

Answer (score 0):

Split the string and cast the part after `#` to an integer

```cs
if (s.Name.Contains("#")) {
  string core_id_str = s.Name.Split('#')[1]; // gets second part of split
  int core_id = System.Convert.ToInt32(core_id_str); // convert to integer
  // do your magic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use switch here because it only works for exact equality whereas you need to do something like:

```
if(s.Name == "Core Average")
{
   // ...
}
else if (s.Name.StartsWith("CPU Core #"))
{
   int coreid = int.Parse(s.Name.Split('#')[1]);
   // ...  
}
```

It doesn't look like you need a further loop as CPU Core 1 .... 64 already seem to be part of thisComputer.Hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stephan, it really helped. So much appreciated!

It works on my 4 core home computer well, but there's **another item** starting with CPU Core #, which has a string after the number. I need to find a way to filter out the latter. Maybe by limiting the if clause to something like "&& lentgh == 11" ?

```
                    if (s.Name.StartsWith("CPU Core #"))
                    {
                        // int coreid = int.Parse(s.Name.Split('#')[1]);
                        string coreid = s.Name.Split('#')[1];
                        coreno = coreid.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER " + coreno + " Temp " + s.Value);
                    }
```

COLSOLE:

```
NAME: CPU Core #1, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 43
>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER 1 Temp 43
NAME: CPU Core #2, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 44
>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER 2 Temp 44
NAME: CPU Core #3, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 43
>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER 3 Temp 43
NAME: CPU Core #4, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 42
>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER 4 Temp 42
NAME: CPU Package, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 44
NAME: CPU Core #1 Distance to TjMax, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 57
>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER 1 Distance to TjMax Temp 57
NAME: CPU Core #2 Distance to TjMax, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 56
>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER 2 Distance to TjMax Temp 56
NAME: CPU Core #3 Distance to TjMax, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 57
>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER 3 Distance to TjMax Temp 57
NAME: CPU Core #4 Distance to TjMax, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 58
>>>>>>>>>>>>> CORE NUMBER 4 Distance to TjMax Temp 58
```

Comment: You will need to adjust this bit

int.Parse(s.Name.Split('#')[1]);

It only works if the string has the format CORE ... #1.

It fails for the name "CPU Core #1 Distance to TjMax" since there is more text after the "#1". You probably should try something like:

int id;
 
foreach(string part in s.Name.Split(' '))
{
 if(part.StartsWith("#"))
  id = int.Parse(part.Split('#')[1]); 
}

Comment: Thanks I bug fixed it a bit and reposted the messy answer. Still working on it haha. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION (update):

```
                        if (s.Name.StartsWith("CPU Core #") && s.Name.Length == 11)
                        {

                            int coreid = int.Parse(s.Name.Split('#')[1]);
                            string corenumber = coreid.ToString();
                            string coreNoTemp = " CORE NUMBER: " + corenumber + " Temp: " + s.Value;

                            coreNoTempStr[coreid] = coreNoTemp.ToString();

                            Console.WriteLine(coreNoTempStr[coreid]);

                        }
```

Console:

```
NAME: CPU Core #1, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 44
CORE NUMBER 1 Temp 44
NAME: CPU Core #2, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 45
CORE NUMBER 2 Temp 45
NAME: CPU Core #3, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 44
CORE NUMBER 3 Temp 44
NAME: CPU Core #4, TYPE: Temperature, VALUE: 44
CORE NUMBER 4 Temp 44
```

The entire string:

***CORE NUMBER: 1 Temp: 41 CORE NUMBER: 2 Temp: 42 CORE NUMBER: 3 Temp: 39 CORE NUMBER: 4 Temp: 40***

THANKS STEFAN!

[image: THX]